# Kendo UI Grid Button Firing Multiple Times

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Sorry for such a huge amount of code, but wanted to be thorough..

Grid 1 has a button - Here is it's code:

```
name: "custom1", text: "View",
click: function(e) {
  $uid = this.dataItem(this.select()).users_id;
  $(".title h4").filter(":first").css({
     color: "#0070c0",
     "text-decoration": "underline",
     cursor: "pointer"
  });
  var offset = $(".grid-box").offset();
  var newLeft = offset.left+25;
  newLeft = newLeft + "px";
  var newTop = offset.top+80;
  newTop = newTop + "px";

  // Get Profile Info
  $.getJSON(
    '/data/get_users_data.php',
    { users_id: $uid })
    .done( function(tempData) {
        $(".echo_users_name").html(tempData.data[0].users_first_name + ' ' + tempData.data[0].users_last_name);
        $("#users_email").html("<a href=\"+tempData.data[0].users_email+\">"+tempData.data[0].users_email+"</a>");
        $("#users_mobile_phone").html(tempData.data[0].users_mobile_phone);


        $('#teamGrid').css("display","none");
        $('.grid-box2').css({
          display: "block",
          position: "absolute",
          top: newTop,
          left: newLeft,
        }); 
        generatePermissionsGrid($uid);
    });
},
```

Clicking on this button hides the grid that houses it, un-hides (css display = block) a div and generates a new grid.  Here is the Grid (Grid #2) that is GENERATED after the click occurs above:

```
function generatePermissionsGrid(uid) {
    $uid = "";
    $uid = uid;
    $("#permissionsGrid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [
            {   title: "Access to Application?", 
                field: "permissions_users_apps_status", 
                attributes: {
                    style: "text-align: center; font-size: 14px;"
                },
                filterable: true,
                headerAttributes: {
                    style: "font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; width: 100px;"
                },
                template: function(dataItem) {
                    if ( dataItem.permissions_users_apps_status == 0 ) {
                        return "<input type='checkbox' name='permissions_users_apps_status' id='permissions_users_apps_status' value='1' />"
                    } else if ( dataItem.permissions_users_apps_status == 1 ) {
                        return "<input type='checkbox' name='permissions_users_apps_status' id='permissions_users_apps_status' value='1' checked />"
                    }
                }
            },
            {   title: "Application Name", 
                field: "apps_title", 
                attributes: {
                    style: "text-align: center; font-size: 14px;"
                },
                filterable: true,
                headerAttributes: {
                    style: "font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; width: 100px;"
                }
            },
            { 
                command: [
                    {   
                        name: "custom3", text: "Update",
                        click: function() {
                        $pid = this.dataItem(this.select()).permissions_users_apps_id;
                        /*var $row = $(this);
                        var enabled = $row.find('#permissions_users_apps_status').attr('checked');*/
                        // Update App Info
                        alert($uid + ' - ' + $pid);
                        $(".k-grid-custom3").off("click");
                        return;
                        $.post(
                            '/data/update_users_permissions.php',
                            { 
                                users_id: $uid,
                                apps_id: $pid 
                            }).done( function(data) {
                                generatePermissionsGrid($uid);
                            });
                        }
                    }/*,
                    {   
                        name: "custom1", text: "Delete",
                        click: function(e) {
                            $pid = this.dataItem(this.select()).permissions_users_apps_id;
                          // Delete Permissions
                          $confirmed = confirm("Are you certain you would like to delete\nremove access to this application from this user?");
                          if ( $confirmed ) {
                              $.post(
                                '/data/delete_users_permissions.php',
                                { 
                                    users_id: uid,
                                    apps_id: $pid
                                })
                                .done( function(data) {
                                    //
                                });
                          }
                        },
                    }*/
                ],
                headerAttributes: {
                    style: "width: 80px;"
                },
                attributes: {
                    style: "text-align: center;"
                },
                title: "&nbsp;"
            }
            ],
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/data/get_users_permissions.php?users_id=" + uid
                },
                update: {
                    url: "/data/update_teammate.php",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: "/data/delete_teammember.php",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                create:  {
                    url: "",
                    type: "POST"    
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "data",
                total: function (result) {
                         result = result.data || result;
                         return result.length;
               },
               model: {
                    id: "permissions_users_apps_id"   
               }
            },
            type: "json" 
        },
        pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSize: 5,
                pageSizes: [
                    5,10,20
                ]
            },
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        autoSync: true,
        scrollable: false,
        selectable: "row",
        reorderable: false
    }); // END: teamGrid

} // END: generateGrid function
```

Now, if I close this generated grid (hide it using css display = none - and I've tried destroying the grid and clearing the div contents - didn't matter) then I click the button above (the first one) to open this grid again - it fires like the button has been pressed twice.  Then close and reopen this grid again using that same button and it fires 3 times.. etc.. etc.  Goes on forever.

I've tried turning "off" the click binding.. nada.

Anyone have any suggestions??

Thanks again, in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So.. found the issue.

In the ".done()" function of the various command buttons, I was recreating the grid from scratch.  This causes click handlers to "stack" onto each other.

The correct way is to simply force a re-read of the datasource.

So, for example if your grid is placed in a div called "permissionsGrid", and you have already generated the grid prior to making this call, you would use the following to re-read the data (causing a refresh of the grid):

```
$("#permissionsGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```

That's it.  Tidy and simple - and works like a charm.

Hope this helps others!  I know the answers were out there - but this seemed like a simple, straight-forward way - and was easy to duplicate.

Enjoy...

Answer (score 0):

To avoid multiple clicks on kendo button, when you clicked the first time, make some progress bar

```
var divTest=  $("#permissionsGrid");
kendo.ui.progress(divTest,true);
```

In ajax call, complete() method disable the progress bar and also read the grid datasource.

```
kendo.ui.progress(divTest, false);
$("#permissionsGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```